# Vue/Typescript: getter with optional field in interface

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have an interface with optional keys:

```
export interface ChannelWithRelationalMeta {  
  _id: string;
  archivedAt?: Date;
}
```

I have a constant `initialChannelData` set as so:

```
export const initialChannelData: ChannelWithRelationalMeta = {
  _id: '',
  archivedAt: new Date()
}
```

In the store I have the following code.

```
currentChannelViewed: ChannelWithRelationalMeta = initialChannelData;

get getCurrentChannelViewed () {
  return this.currentChannelViewed;
}

@Action
async fetchChannelData (slug) {
  const channel = await ChannelService.channelSlugSlugGet({ slug: slug });
  this.SET_CURRENT_CHANNEL_VIEWED({ channel: channel });
}

@Mutation
SET_CURRENT_CHANNEL_VIEWED (input: { channel: ChannelWithRelationalMeta }) {
  this.currentChannelViewed = input.channel;
}

@Mutation
SET_ARCHIVED_AT (input: { archivedAt: Date }) {
  this.currentChannelViewed.archivedAt = input.archivedAt;
}

@Mutation
REMOVE_ARCHIVED_AT () {
  delete this.currentChannelViewed.archivedAt;
}
```

The vue store updates all the fields from the interface that are not optional. All those mutations work exactly as expected. However, the mutations on this optional key `archivedAt` are not being reflected in the template code. I can run either mutation and the store does show the changes in the dev tools. However, if I print the results of `getCurrentChannelViewed` onto the page the archivedAt field does not update. As such all the reactivity I have in the template code based on that is not working.

Is there an issue with optional fields and the vuex watcher or is there something I need to do differently to set it running properly with optional fields?

Comment: It's unclear where is the problem, not all relevant code has been provided. Types don't affect how it behaves at runtime. But if you didn't specify archivedAt in initial data then archivedAt won't be reactive, this is how Vue 2 reactivity works

Comment: @EstusFlask The field archivedAt is set in the constant. Have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: But it's defined in your example. You didn't show this, "if the store starts with this.currentChannelViewed.archivedAt as undefined"